# How to access Telerik's RadPivotGrid datasource as a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, telerik, pivot-table

I tried casting using the code below without success

```
  DataTable dt=(DataTable)RadPivotGrid1.DataSource;

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You do not need the table :   GridView1.DataSource = RadPivotGrid1.DataSource;

Comment: i need convert it to datatable because i need add some additional data to my pivot table . so please tell me how can i change it to data table

Comment: What type object is the RadPivotGrid1.DataSource (right click on object and go to definition)?  If you really need a datatable you will need to generate the table.  It would be easier to modify the existing datasource to add additional fields.

Comment: public abstract class RadCompositeDataBoundControl   ....   //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the object from which the data-bound control retrieves its list
        //     of data items.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An object that represents the data source from which the data-bound control retrieves
        //     its data. The default is null.
        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        public override object DataSource { get; set; }

Comment: how can i generate table ? i think Telerik have option to give me datatable instead i gererated

Comment: how can i access to data in pivot table to get and set row and col in radpivotGrid?

Comment: It is better to update the query that is filling the datasource with additional columns.  Otherwise, you would need to create a new table and copy all existing data into table and then add additional data for new fields.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: i must get pivot table data and then add some additional col base on pivot table . so please tell me how exactly get DataTable from the pivot table

Comment: You can't.  They are not the same type object.  You may be able to clone the existing pivot table.

Comment: Grammar changes

Comment: what is mean? "Grammar changes"

Comment: I used this but it not work   https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/pivotgrid/iterating-cells